# Google App Engine--Dynamically created templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, django-templates

I'm trying to build an a simple CRUD admin section of my application. Basically, for a given Model, I want to have a template loop through the model's attributes into a simple table (once I do this, I can actually implement the CRUD part). A possible way to accomplish this is to dynamically generate a template with all the necessary template tags specific to that model.

Pseudocode:

```
def generate_tamplate(model):
     template.write("<table border='1'>")
     template.write("<tr>")
     for attribute in model:
          template.write("<td>%s</td>" % attribute)
     template.write("</tr>")
     template.write("<tr>")
     for attribute in model:
          template.write("<td>{{ %s.%s }}</td>" % model.attribute)
     template.write("</tr>")
     template.write("</table>")
```

Generating the proper text should not be difficult. I can follow my pseudocode model and do it Python. Two things im wondering:
1) Can I do this instead using Django's templating language? that is, use a template to generate a template
2) Once I generate the text, how can I wrote that to a file that webapp's template loader can access?

I remember a while back seeing something about loading template from the database. Is this possible with GAE?

THANKS!

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a ModelForm (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this open source project a while back: 
http://code.google.com/p/gae-django-dbtemplates/

Using a template to generate a template should be fine.  Just render the template to a string.  Here some code i use so i can stick some xml into memecache

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'line_chart.xml')
xml = template.render(path, template_values)
```

You can easily do something very similar and stick the result in the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of doing `template.writes`, you can generate the next template - since `template.render(...)` just returns text.   You can then store the text returned and put it into the DataStore, then retrieve it later and call `.render(Context(...))` on it to return the html you want to generate.

You cannot write the generated template to a file - as AppEngine applications do not have write access to the filesystem, only read access.

If you change your '`generate_tamplate`' function to use a template, the pseudocode could look like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

def generate_tamplate(model):
    t = template.render(path_to_template1.html, Context({'model':model}))
    DataStoreTemplate(template=t, name=model.name).put()

''' Later, when you want to generate your page for that model '''
def generate_page(model):
    t = DataStoreTemplate.all().filter("name =",model.name).get().template
    htmlresult = t.render(Context({'model':model}))
    return htmlresult
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, that in my opinion simplifies writing apps for GAE a lot, is using user other templating language, like [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), that allows you to embed Python code in the template, thus no fiddling required.
You would pass model data to the template (as simple as `template.render(template_file, model=model`), and the template would look something like this:

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
      % for attribute in model:
        <td>${attribute}</td>
      % endfor
  </tr>
  <tr>
      % for attribute in model:
        <td>${model.attribute}</td>
      % endfor
  </tr>
</table>
```

I followed [this googled blog entry](http://blog.pansapiens.com/2008/06/24/mako-templates-in-google-app-engine-seems-to-work-for-me/) to get Mako in my app - it was quite simple and works like a charm.