# Mako templates with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, mako

I want to use Mako templates with GAE instead of Django templates. I found this post http://blog.pansapiens.com/2008/06/24/mako-templates-in-google-app-engine-seems-to-work-for-me/

I downloaded Mako from this page by using easy_install http://www.makotemplates.org/download.html

But that gave me a "beaker" file

c:\python26\lib\site-packages\beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg

that I don't know what to do with.

Can someone help me so that I can get "Mako" file to put in my GAE directory as instructed in the blog.

I saw the reference to Mako/GAE here [Google App Engine--Dynamically created templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744828/google-app-engine-dynamically-created-templates)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Mako on App Engine.  It works very well for me.

All I do is [download](http://www.makotemplates.org/downloads/Mako-0.3.4.tar.gz) mako directly, then place the mako module directory in my app root.

Comment: Thanks! I have the folder Mako-0.3.4. Is that the mako module? And what is the correct from-import language that I need to use in the script. Thanks again.

Comment: You want the `mako` folder that is inside the Mako-0.3.4 folder.  Then you can use the command from the guide you found, `from mako.template import Template` and so on.

Comment: That gives an error: File "C:\Users\A\Desktop\hw2\mako\filters.py", line 11, in <module>
    import markupsafe
ImportError: No module named markupsafe

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that.  Edit `filters.py`, change line 11 (`import markupsafe`) to `import cgi` then change line 25 (`return markupsafe.escape(string)`) to `return cgi.escape(string)`.

Comment: Or download also [MarkupSafe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe). You then don't need to alter Mako source code.

Comment: If you look at `setup.py` for mako, it clearly states that there is a dependency with `MarkupSafe`.

Comment: Ah, ran into a pretty big problem here.  Mako needs to create temporary files by default.  It doesn't seem like there's a way to change template.py to allow it to do that, since Google App Engine doesn't make temporary files.  Did you find a work-around for this?

Comment: The awesome team that wrote the aha framework actually figured this out. The mako_patch function here makes Mako store temporary files in memcache instead of on the filesystem: http://code.google.com/p/aha-gae/source/browse/aha/controller/makocontroller.py

Comment: @Milimetric  I've never encountered an issue with that on App Engine.  However, I've not updated mako in any projects for a few months though, so perhaps that is why.

Comment: @Robert Kluin, makes sense: I'm using 0.4.2 so maybe _compile_module_file is new to Mako.  I haven't done any performance testing yet but I think compiling it to memcache should be great.  I can't imagine having more than a few MB of template files altogether in my case.

Comment: I switched to django from Mako. Mako is great and I would've stayed with Mako unless I needed i18n with .po files and some less than most common tags. Mako is very readable but django has many more components.