# Mako with Google App Engine - What do you do about temporary files?

Tags: google-app-engine, mako

I modified my Google App Engine app to work with Mako.  To do this, I followed this answer including the comments:

[Mako templates with Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938963/mako-templates-with-google-app-engine)

However, once you get to loading templates from files, you run into a big problem.  By default, Mako's Template from mako/template.py wants to create a temporary file to store your compiled template.  As far as I can tell, GAE doesn't allow you to create a temp file though.  Has anyone run into this and figured out a work-around?

Comment: The awesome team that wrote the aha framework actually figured this out.  The mako_patch function here makes Mako store temporary files in memcache instead of on the filesystem: http://code.google.com/p/aha-gae/source/browse/aha/controller/makocontroller.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awesome team that wrote the aha framework actually figured this out. The mako_patch function here makes Mako store temporary files in memcache instead of on the filesystem: http://code.google.com/p/aha-gae/source/browse/aha/controller/makocontroller.py

EDIT: as @Nick Johnson points out, storing this in local memory would make just as much sense and not incur the cost of memcache.

Comment: Storing it in local instance memory would likely be a better idea - there's no need to use memcache here.

Comment: +1 that makes sense.  I was just glad to get it to work and didn't stop to think.